# NSMutableArray EXC_BAD_ACCESS on contained objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I have a class where I implement a NSMutableArray of objects. Now, when the phone goes into landscape mode, all of the objects in the NSMutableArray are deleted from the view (but not from the NSMutableArray), then when the phone goes back to portrait mode, I put all the objects contained in the NSMutableArray into the view, but when I try to access the first object I receive: EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

This is my code:

```
- (void) setObjects:(BOOL)hidden andWindow:(UIWindow *)win andTxt:(UITextView *)txt andTarget:(id) target {
    //view
    key = [win.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    key.hidden = hidden;
    buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; //my array
    txtsms = txt;
        [...]
}

- (void) addButton:(button *)but {
    [key addSubview:[but returnButton]];
    [buttons addObject:but];
    [but release];
}

- (void) hiddenAllKey {
    for (UIView *subview in [key subviews])
        if ((subview.tag <= startSpecialPunctuation+1)&&(subview.tag >= spaceButton+1)) 
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void) showAllKey {   
    for(int i = 0; i < [buttons count]; ++i)
             [key addSubview:[[buttons objectAtIndex:i] returnButton]]; //this is the problem :|
}
```

Comment: @Joe - you are right, there is no 'could be' about it. If you dint create or retain the button it shouldn't be released here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) hiddenAllKey {
    for (UIView *subview in [key subviews])
        if ((subview.tag <= startSpecialPunctuation+1)&&(subview.tag >= spaceButton+1)) 
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This is subtly wrong too. You are removing elements from a list you are enumerating using fast enumeration. It can (should) fail easily.

Previously, I've written a category on UIView to do a remove all, that was doable with a simple while loop. Now, what you're trying to do... you might do a for loop where you manage the iterated index yourself, ie when you don't remove, you increment, else you keep it the same.

EDIT: suggestion of solution:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < [[key subviews] count]; )
{
    UIView *subview = [[key subviews] objectAtIndex: idx];
    if ((subview.tag <= startSpecialPunctuation + 1) && (subview.tag >= spaceButton + 1))
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else
    {
        idx++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you link me your solution?

Comment: I'll edit my answer with a possible solution for *your* case, which is not what I was doing in my case.

Comment: Well, I can't test it right now, it might not work due to removeFromSuperview nature :(

Comment: I'm sure the while (list != empty) removeView; loop does work though, so this should be feasible.

Comment: The problems is that I have a textField, if I remove it, doesn't work your code (and my code), If I hidden it, your code (and mine) works fine...I don't understand why :|

Comment: Maybe a tag problem? Or the order of the list changes? Without knowing really well your project, it's hard to tell.

Comment: this is the problem: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388126/removing-a-uitextfield-involve-tha-calling-of-keyboarddidshow)

Answer (score 3):

As Joe Blow said, this is wrong:

```
- (void) addButton:(button *)but {
    [key addSubview:[but returnButton]];
    [buttons addObject:but];
    [but release];
}
```

`but` should not be released in that method.  Similarly, this strikes fear in my heart:

```
- (void) setObjects:(BOOL)hidden andWindow:(UIWindow *)win andTxt:(UITextView *)txt andTarget:(id) target {
    //view
    key = [win.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    key.hidden = hidden;
    buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; //my array
```

Where do you release `buttons`?   Does your app only ever call that method once? If not, then you'll be leaking `buttons`.

Try `build and analyze` on your code, fixing any problems that it identifies.  If it still crashes, post the backtrace of the crash